# Delphi's Sharemem - When it is not needed

Tags: delphi, memory, dll

I know that when I share `strings` between a Delphi APP and a Delphi DLL I need to add `Sharemem` in both app and dll project source as the first unit in uses clause.

But, if the dll exports function that accept only `Pchars` but inside some of the dll methods I use `strings`, should I use sharemem as well? Let me shown a sample code:

```
procedure ShowMyCustomMessage(aMessage : Pchar);
var
  vUselessString : string;
begin
  vUselessString := aMessage;
  ShowMessage(vUselessString);
end;

exports
  ShowMyCustomMessage;
```

In that simple and useless case, the dll is accepting a `Pchar` but inside the exported method the dll creates a `string` var. Should I add `ShareMem` as well?

What about `WideString`? Does passing `WideString` parameters require the use of `Sharemem`?

Comment: AFAIK `ShareMem` is to be used if you want to use the deprecated borlndmm.dll memory manager. But this is not a good idea since Delphi 2007. You shall better use SimpleShareMem which is based on FastMM4 and is *much* faster.

Comment: @Arnaud are you sure about borlndmm being deprecated? I have not seen anybody talking about it.

Comment: @RafaelColucci: the *old* borlndmm.dll.  Confusingly, all memory manager DLLs have this name.  The current version of Delphi / C++ Builder uses FastMM, compiled to 'borlndmm.dll', and has for several years now.

Comment: IMHO using an external library is a deprecated technology to be used only if one of the library is not able to be recompiled with FastMM4. In fact, FastMM4 has a built-in sharing system (based on a per-process mapped file) avoiding use of the external borlndmm.dll file, which is only here for backward compatibility with third-party libraries which you do not have the source.

Comment: This is an old thread, but I wanted to add that using ShareMem provides the wonderful ability to switch out the memory manager without recompiling.  For example, I have a optimized FastMM, a "fulldebug" FastMM, and then the killer SafeMM.

As our servers are multi-threaded, this also allows us to easily benchmark memory managers while performance tuning.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to use Sharemem if and only if memory is allocated in one module (i.e. DLL/EXE) and deallocated in a different module. This commonly happens when you are working passing `string` between modules.

In the example you give, there is no need to use Sharemem. The memory for the `PChar` is allocated by the called and is not deallocated by the callee. The string in the callee is allocated and deallocated in the callee.

Here's an example where you would need Sharemem:

```
function GetString: string;
begin
  Result := 'hello';
end;
```

Here the memory for the string is allocated in the callee but will be deallocated by the caller.

The case of a `WideString` is quite special. The `WideString` is a wrapper around the COM `BSTR` type. It allocates and deallocates using the shared COM allocator. So it does not use the Delphi allocator and you are safe to pass `WideString` between modules without using Sharemem.

Comment: nice to know, but what if instead of Pchar the dll accepts a widestring?

Comment: i know, that was just a plus. Thanks for everything.