# Is OleVariant usable for out parameter in DLL proc?

Tags: string, delphi, dll, parameters

I want to make an interface, but I don't know something.

Is `OleVariant` a  "standard" for containing "standard" string - to pass and return?

```
function Any(Input : OleVariant; out Output : OleVariant) : integer; stdcall;
```

The another side is maybe .NET, C#, or C++ or Delphi.

So can they back some "string" result in `OleVariant` without I pass a predefined sized buffer for result?

Comment: Use WideString for passing string variables and save yourself the trouble. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414972/delphis-sharemem-when-it-is-not-needed) for some additional pointers

Comment: OleVariant will *not* contain a "standard" string (if a standard string is a Delphi string). When you assign a string to an OleVariant the string will be converted to a "WideString".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, `OleVariant` is perfectly safe. You'll see it used throughout the COM-related units distributed with Delphi, such as ActiveX, ComSvcs, and MSXML. Standard Windows API units use it, so you can, too.

If you're always expecting a string, though, then you should prefer `WideString` instead. It's equivalent to the Windows `BSTR` type.