# How to properly call a DLL dynamically

Tags: delphi

I tried to follow this tutorial [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dll/dll_delphi_example.htm) but its always throwing access violation error druing **FreeLibary**. Where did I go wrong? Here is my DLL code :

```
library EditDocument;

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  Vcl.Dialogs,
  System.Classes,
  dxmdaset;

{$R *.res}



procedure EditDocument2(const fieldName : string); stdcall;
begin
  ShowMessage(fieldName);
end;


exports EditDocument2;

begin
end.
```

and this is how I called it in my main program :

```
procedure TfrmMain.btn1Click(Sender: TObject);
type
  TDLL_EditDocument = procedure (const fieldName : string); stdcall;

var
  dllHandle : THandle;
  aFunction : TDLL_EditDocument;
begin

  dllHandle := LoadLibrary('EditDocument.dll') ;

  if dllHandle = 0 then
  begin
    CommonHelper.MsgDlgError('DLL not found EditDocument.dll');
    Exit;
  end;

  @aFunction := GetProcAddress(dllHandle, 'EditDocument2') ;
  if Assigned (aFunction) then
  begin
    aFunction('test');
  end;

  FreeLibrary(dllHandle);


end;
```

Also, I have use **Sharemem** in my main project, its the first unit in the uses clause. I have tried changing stdcall to cdecl, making parameters to shortstring, and even removing all parameters but its always throwing error during FreeLibrary. I'm sure this is an easy one but it already cost me 2 hours.
I'm using Delphi XE7.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is there any `Initialization` or `Finalization` code in your `dxmdaset` unit, or any of your own units that it USEs?

Comment: there is none.. I removed everything..

Comment: I removed the **dxmdaset** in the uses clause and its now ok.. this is bad because my main objective is to pass a TdxMemData as parameter

Comment: Well, now you know the source, ime it shouldn't take you very long to identify what the source of the problem is.  I would say "good luck" but you don't need luck, just patience and resolve.

Comment: Why not just build a single monolithic executable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `Sharemem` you need to use it in the DLL project also. It is missing from your DLL project's use clause.

Beyond that error, the most likely suspect for your error is the finalization code of one of the units that you use. Given that the RTL and VCL units are known to handle dynamic loading and unloading, that points the finger at `dxmdaset`. Try removing that unit from your DLL.

Finally, sometimes external DLLs will raise first chance exceptions that trigger in the debugger, but do not actually cause any problem. Have you made 100% sure that the call to `FreeLibrary` does not in fact return successfully. You can do this by capturing and outputting the return value of `FreeLibrary`.

Comment: put ShareMem in both EXE and DLL still error.  then remove sharemem and parameters and still error.. not sure what is happening

Comment: @Ago: you already found out that the problem is unit *dxmdaset*. Just debug that and find out where it goes wrong.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Sharemem`, it needs to be the first unit in both the main project *and* the library.

When you remove all parameters that shouldn't be an issue (see also [Sharemem, when is it not needed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8414972/delphis-sharemem-when-it-is-not-needed)), but perhaps you didn't compile both projects when you tried that. When you just hit compile/run, or even build, only the current project will be compiled. Make sure you run Project -> Build All when you're playing around with the signature of the procedure.